# PHPDoc for PDO Wrapper

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm, phpdoc

While writing a lightweight wrapper for PDO I noticed that the PDO::Query method seems to have 4 different signatures available to use as per the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Method overloading is not allowed in PHP and it seems that PHPDoc doesn't like this scenario, at least while using PHPStorm 8.x and the following code (I provided only two signature for this example):

```
<?php

/**
 * @method \PDOStatement query(string $statement)
 * @method \PDOStatement query(string $statement, int $PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, int $colno)
 */
class Database
{

    private $PDO;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $pass = null, $options = null)
    {
        $this->PDO = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$this->PDO, $method), $arguments);
    }
}
```

Of course the second @method statement is highlighted in red in PHPStorm with the following error:

**"Method with same name already defined in this class"**

Does anyone has a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: The relationship between your `Database` and `PDO` have to be `is-a`, not `has-a`. That's violation of LSP and SRP

Comment: 1) Why don't you look how PDO is declared in PhpStorm itself? 2) Yes -- you cannot declare multiple signatures of the same method -- it's true for PHPDoc, PhpStorm and PHP itself. The only way is to have the most complete implementation and mark all other fields as optional (that have default value).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, that's what I thought but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @bad_boy So if I understand correctly your comment, you would inject the PDO object in the database constructor and remove the __call method? From a usability standpoint all that would change is that I have to call `Database::PDO->method` rather than `Database::PDOmethod` ? The only advantage I see is that it could prevent some PHPdoc issues in the event they change PDO.

Comment: What you should understand is that, `PDO` is not part of your application logic, including that `Database` wrapper. It's part of **data storage abstraction**. And storage abstraction classes, like `PDO` should only be used in classes that abstract table rows manipulation. (see *TableGateway* and *DataMapper* patters). And no, I would only inject **one** prepared/configured `PDO` instance to all data mappers.

Comment: The way you want to comment a class is kind of old-fashioned. Look at modern PHP libraries/frameworks. Nobody comments like this.

Comment: @bad_boy Actually I thought I was already looking at modern comparative and also some online documentation to pull this off. Do you have any recommendation for other information source I should be looking at? I'll read on those patterns to understand what I am missing.

Comment: Well, you can look at how industry leaders such as Symfony2.5+, Zend 2 + and Laravel4+ approach commenting their code. What I recommend you is to read at spare time about these things: SOLID, Service (A bridge between data mapper and domain objects)

Comment: Keep in mind, that another people don't want to read all your code. They want your API and your clear documentation (how to use API to make things work), not code itself.

Comment: @bad_boy Yes I have no doubt I could benefit from more lecture. On the other hand I just spot checked my local Symfony and Zend installs (latest versions) and they use the same format I use for documentation. It just happens that the snippet I provided was focused on this topic. Or did I miss anything when you said that my format was old school?

Comment: When I mentioned old-school comments, I was refering to `/**
 * @method \PDOStatement query(string $statement)
 * @method \PDOStatement query(string $statement, int $PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, int $colno)
 */` The comments above class definition. Nowhere in ZF or SF you can encounter that

Comment: @bad_boy Hmm I'm not sure what you mean? I see some comments close to that in ZF's AbstractController for example. Of course the second comment line on my question was from PHP's website since I didn't know how to implement it anyway. But thanks for the tip